# Groovy HTTP Builder: Empty POST response causes SAXParseException

Tags: java, groovy, httpbuilder

I am implementing REST client for YouTrack API. I am getting an exception whenever my POST requests return empty response (there's just a valid header). The HTTP status code is 200.
That's the stacktrace:

```
[Fatal Error] :-1:-1: Premature end of file.
gru 03, 2013 10:34:49 AM groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder doRequest
WARNING: Error parsing 'application/xml; charset=UTF-8' response
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file.
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at groovy.util.XmlSlurper.parse(XmlSlurper.java:181)
at groovy.util.XmlSlurper.parse(XmlSlurper.java:234)
at groovyx.net.http.ParserRegistry.parseXML(ParserRegistry.java:267)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:952)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:439)
at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.parseResponse(HTTPBuilder.java:561)
at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:494)
at groovyx.net.http.RESTClient.post(RESTClient.java:140)
at groovyx.net.http.RESTClient$post.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at groovy.YouTrackRest.releaseVersion(YouTrackRest.groovy:66)
at groovy.YouTrackRest$releaseVersion$0.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at YouTrack.run(YouTrack.groovy:13)
[...]
```

I have debugged and found out what's the direct cause for that. I noticed that in groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder:492 before parsing it is checked whether response is empty but in my case the call entity.getContentLength() returns -1. After [Apache documentation for HttpEntity](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/BasicHttpEntity.html#getContentLength%28%29)
the number of bytes of the content, or a negative number if unknown

My client implementation is very plain. I have worked the problem around by catching the HttpResponseException and asserting statusCode 200. I am still getting the stacktrace in my console, but that's probably just the logger setting.

My implementation:

```
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient

class YouTrackRest extends RESTClient { 
[...]
def activateVersion(versionNumber) {
    try {
        post(
                path: getVersionPath(versionNumber),
                body: [
                        colorIndex: ACTIVE_COLOR_INDEX,
                        released: false,
                        releaseDate: null,
                        archived: false,
                        newName: versionNumber

                ]
        )
    } catch (HttpResponseException ex) {
        assert ex.response.status == 200
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**
These are the response headers

```
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 06 Dec 2013 10:36:10 GMT
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=ny2s3cxwsvveya6vgwj2fmig;Path=/youtrack
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, no-transform, must-revalidate
```

Present `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header explains missing 'Content-Length' header. That has to be the reason for unknown Content Length. 
Now, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) *The data transfer is terminated by a final chunk of length zero*. So maybe is this case the first chunk is also the last one?

Both, the Web Server and the Http client library are third party for me. I would like to raise an issue by whoever misbehaves:

- either YouTrack REST WS *promisses* XML and returns nothing
- or `groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder` fails to process chunked encoded responses.

I will be very helpful for some expertise to help me understand the problem.

Comment: Looks like it's expecting xml in the response, but it's not getting any

Comment: @tim_yates, please read my 'EDIT' in question. Do you think that an empty response chunk and `application/xml` Content-Type are misbehavior of the WS?

Comment: If the response is empty then the server should really be sending 204 rather than 200.

Comment: I have reported an issue at [YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-22854)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was caused by non-standard WS response: HTTP status 200 and empty response body. Either HTTP status 204 is expected, or valid XML body and status 200.

I have reported an [issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-22854) at WS providers. Hopefully it will get resolved. I am marking the question as answered

Thanks @tim_yates and @Ian Roberts for your helpful comments.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this same problem using [httpbuilder](/questions/tagged/httpbuilder). I was able to work around it with:

```
def service = new HTTPBuilder(...)
service.request(Method.POST, ContentType.JSON) {
    uri.path = ...
    body = ...

    response.'200' = { resp ->
            logInfo resp.statusLine
    }

    response.success = { resp, result ->
            logInfo resp.statusLine
    }

    response.failure = { resp ->
            logError resp.statusLine
    }
}
```

Essentially do not try to parse the body, if response is 200.

Comment: This happened to me too but for status code 201. Just changing 200 to 201 worked fine: response.'201' = { resp ->